# What is the reason of the crash at CFNetWork _CFURLRequestCopyContentDispositionEncodingFallbackArray

Tags: crash, segmentation-fault, cfnetwork

This crash is from crash report of app. Multiple URL requests crash cause of it. I want to figure out how to repeat the crash and why the crash happened.

```
Incident Identifier: 4A2BA2B1-9174-410F-9D51-88A151884484
CrashReporter Key:   TODO
Hardware Model:      iPhone8,1
Code Type:       ARM-64
Parent Process:  ??? [1]

Date/Time:       2016-09-28 02:43:26 +0000
OS Version:      iPhone OS 10.0.2 (14A456)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  SIGSEGV
Exception Codes: SEGV_ACCERR at 0x0
Crashed Thread:  21

Thread 21 Crashed:
0   CFNetwork                           _CFURLRequestCopyContentDispositionEncodingFallbackArray + 48
1   CFNetwork                           HTTPProtocol::updateForHeader(__CFHTTPMessage*) + 260
2   CFNetwork                           HTTPProtocol::performHeaderReadPostProcessing(__CFHTTPMessage*, unsigned char) + 156
3   CFNetwork                           HTTPProtocol::performHeaderRead(__CFHTTPMessage*) + 992
4   CFNetwork                           HTTPProtocol::handleStreamEvent(__CFHTTPMessage*, dispatch_data_s*, CFStreamError const*) + 496
5   CFNetwork                           ___ZN15HTTPTransaction22_onqueue_invokeHandlerEv_block_invoke.64 + 60
6   libdispatch.dylib                   _dispatch_client_callout + 16
7   libdispatch.dylib                   _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 376
8   CFNetwork                           RunloopBlockContext::_invoke_block(void const*, void*) + 36
9   CoreFoundation                      CFArrayApplyFunction + 68
10  CFNetwork                           RunloopBlockContext::perform() + 136
11  CFNetwork                           MultiplexerSource::perform() + 312
12  CFNetwork                           MultiplexerSource::_perform(void*) + 64
13  CoreFoundation                      __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
14  CoreFoundation                      __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 524
15  CoreFoundation                      __CFRunLoopRun + 804
16  CoreFoundation                      CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
17  CFNetwork                           +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 336
18  Foundation                          __NSThread__start__ + 1024
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib             _pthread_body + 240
20  libsystem_pthread.dylib             _pthread_body + 0
21  libsystem_pthread.dylib             thread_start + 4
```

Comment: This crash ONLY happened in iOS 10，iOS 9 and before works fine

Comment: Hello @钟少奋, Did you resolve this issue? What versions did you see this crash in? Did you see the crash only in 10.3.1?

Comment: @DevDude I had the same question, then I noticed that the header reports: 10.0.2